# How to insert mysql database in a new file?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know how can i put the table from mysql in a new file.php.

**I want the MySql table to be on the page.**

This is my code that inserts data in MySql.

```
<?php

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("host", "id_", "password", "xxxxxx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$Task = $_POST['Task'];
$Date = $_POST['Date'];
$Desc = $_POST['Desc'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tasklist (Task, Date, Description)
        VALUES ('$Task', '$Date', '$Desc')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);

?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="addtask.php" method="post">
            Task: <input type="text" name="Task">
            Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="Date">
            Decrption:<textarea type="text" name="Desc"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _I want the MySQL table to be on the page_? Do you mean to say that you want to retrieve the rows from the table and display them on another page with PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show values from a mySQL database table inside a html table in a page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page)

Comment: Note that your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Now is the time to properly learn to use [`prepare()/execute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) in MySQLi.

Comment: Read over [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and look at the MySQLi examples using prepared statements and bound parameters.

Comment: Yes @MichaelBerkowski , and about injection i know about that ,i will not go live with it .Im trying to learn to do this first.Ty

Comment: Your welcome , adding it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

also u can try w3schools  sample code :

Display the Result in an HTML Table
The following example selects the same data as the example above, but will display the data in an HTML table:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

The output of the code above will be:

[image]

first code comes from "[Jonnny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895169/jonnny)" in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page)