# Table not displaying any results in a array-query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to display the results of a database on a webpage. Using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page), I have come up with this piece of php code below:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("217.199.187.70","cl52-domains","######","cl52-domains");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $results = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM domains");

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Domain</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['domain_name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['domain_address'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

However, when I refresh my webpage, it shows the table header (no errors), but 0 results. Here is my table specifications:

[image]
[image]

Can someone tell me why I'm not getting any results?

Comment: You assign to `$results`, you read from `$result` (no `s`). Is that in the real code or a copying error? You should enable warnings when developing, then you'll see the notice about the undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

To

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
```

You probably made a typo in referencing the $results variable.

Comment: Thank you! It works! Yes silly error on my side, I thought it was a SQL issue (hence screenshots of tables), but should have guessed it was a reference typo...