# Simple mySql-php data display

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to display things from database in table in html. I found this example on somewhere on intertet and followed whole guide until I came there . It shows table and all but instead putting informations that are on database it just puts in "$data[1]" and "$data[0]". 
Thanks it advance

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search data</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">EMPLOYEES DATA</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>NAME</td>            
        <td>ADDRESS</td>
      </tr>
<?php
//the example of searching data 
with the sequence based on the field name
//search.php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");//database connection
mysql_select_db("employees");

$order = "SELECT * FROM data_employees ORDER BY name";
//order to search data
//declare in the order variable

$result = mysql_query($order);  
//order executes the result is saved
//in the variable of $result

while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo("<tr><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[0]</td></tr>");
}
?>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you can, you should [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and consider using PDO, [it's really not hard](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html). You should also add error checking, such as `or die(mysql_error())` to your queries. Or you can find the issues in your current error logs.

Comment: *"it just puts in "$data[1]" and "$data[0]"."* - is the file `.php` extension? server running? and is this part of the code? `with the sequence based on the field name` shouldn't be there.

Comment: **Install a web server** or if on a hosted site, rename your file to `file.php`. there; fixed.

Comment: are these comments even being read *Sam?* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *I don't know Ralph.* Seems everyone left @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've made both , .php and .html , server is running and it's still not working . I'm not good with this sql and php , it's new thing to me

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Probably get a deprecated notice, who knows. check for errors.

Comment: @Fred-ii- where it will report errors ? I can't see any reports of errors

Comment: if you're not seeing anything on screen, then you have server problems. check your logs. If this doesn't work `<?php echo "Hello world"; ?>` then you'll know where to look. far as I'm concerned, your code checks out. minus the `with the sequence based on the field name`

Comment: anyway, you have another answer below, ask them http://stackoverflow.com/a/30668347/

Comment: @Fred-ii- looks like server is fine . it says hello world

Comment: Do this now then `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); <html>
<head>
<title>Search data</title>` followed by the rest of your code.

Comment: Guys i got it , a comment in line 19 . look at it , i forgot to type "//" .

Comment: I'm sorry , my english skills are not good , I didnt knew what that means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this

```
//the example of searching data 
with the sequence based on the field name
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that should have been commented out.

I told you twice in comments.

> "it just puts in "$data[1]" and "$data[0]"." - is the file .php extension? server running? and is this part of the code? `with the sequence based on the field name` shouldn't be there. –  Fred -ii- 25 mins ago

and

> if you're not seeing anything on screen, then you have server problems. check your logs. If this doesn't work  then you'll know where to look. far as I'm concerned, your code checks out. minus the `with the sequence based on the field name` –  Fred -ii- 8 mins ago

that is the error, not the other answer(s).

- Let the record be clear here.

Error reporting told you where the error was, as I stated in comments.

> Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`. Probably get a deprecated notice, who knows. check for errors. –  Fred -ii- 14 mins ago

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

---

Just an added note:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling array variables in double quotes, where array variable can't display like this as normal variables. They also considered as string, so it displays the array variables. There are two ways to display the actual value.

```
Way1:
echo "<tr><td>".$data[1]."</td><td>".$data[0]."</td></tr>";
Way2:
echo "<tr><td>{$data[1]}</td><td>{$data[0]}</td></tr>";
```

I Prefer way1 as the second way leads to low execution speed.

Comment: I got it , it's working now

Answer (score -2):

this is really a standart question.....full of answers in the web. you need to call the values correctly...

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
  echo("<tr><td>".$data[1]."</td><td>".$data[0]."</td></tr>");
}
```

just like here:

[Show values from a mySQL database table inside a html table in a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page)

but you should use mysqli:

http://tut.php-quake.net/en/mysql-php.html

Comment: It's still not working , but thanks for answer.

Comment: so try the following:
`while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo("<tr><td>".$data[1]."</td><td>".$data[0]."</td></tr>");
}` @Jay Blanchard: this is correct, but it is a bit dirty, so i never would use this

Comment: but the post i posted does

Comment: how you can see from the OP's voted "solved problem answer" this was no serverside problem.....but thanks to god you downrated all these other answers xD

Comment: You can see from the OP's comments that he had a typo @messerbill so it was a syntax error. As I stated, none of the answers here would fix the OP's problem. You know you can delete this answer and get your points back.