# Join single column of single table to multiple column of another table

Tags: mysql, join

Here is what I have tried so far.But it showed an error.

#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'club'

```
select members.*, role.role_name, department.dept_name, club.club_name from members
join role on members.role_id=role.id
join department on members.dept_id=department.id
join club on members.club_id=club.id
join club on members.coordi_club_id = club.id
```

How can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please:

```
SELECT
    members.*, role.role_name,
    department.dept_name,
    CL1.club_name
FROM
    members
JOIN role ON members.role_id = role.id
JOIN department ON members.dept_id = department.id
JOIN club CL1 ON members.club_id = CL1.id
JOIN club CL2 ON members.coordi_club_id = CL2.id;
```

**Note:** You needed to give an alias to `club` table while joining the second time. For the sake of clarity I've used two aliases of `club` table `(CL1,CL2)`.

**EDIT:** Since you are joining `club` table with the same instance of `members` table the second join becomes redundant this way.

Instead you should use the following query:

```
    SELECT
        members.*, role.role_name,
        department.dept_name,
        CL1.club_name
    FROM
        members
    JOIN role ON members.role_id = role.id
    JOIN department ON members.dept_id = department.id
    JOIN club CL1 ON members.club_id = CL1.id AND members.coordi_club_id = CL1.id;
```

Comment: I've one more doubt. Can you please tell me how to fetch this values on my php page .

Comment: Please look at this [**post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-in-a-page) and [**more**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should not join a table multiple times in a single statement. Erase the last join part of your code, hope it will work fine.

```
select members.*, role.role_name, department.dept_name, club.club_name from members
join role on members.role_id=role.id
join department on members.dept_id=department.id
join club on members.club_id=club.id ;    // If you want to add another condition, just write AND keyword and specify in this line.

join club on members.coordi_club_id = club.id //   You need not use this line
```