# How to display entire MySQL table without entering table name in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code is given below. In which I can only print the table headings. I want the table whose name I entered in the database should show the entire table.

```
<?php

$dataconn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "databasename");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM employeedetails";
$res = mysqli_query($dataconn, $sql);
$show = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$col = $show[0];
$columns = array();

echo "<pre>";
foreach ($col as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($key)) {
        $columns[] = $key;
    }
}
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
foreach ($columns as $value) {
    echo "<th>$value</th>";
}
for ($x = 0; $x < count($show); $x++) {
    echo "$value";
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($res as $row)` should do it i think... although question title, and question body dont match up

Comment: Can you edit the question it self, It doesn't match with what are you looking for

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/64296838/1839439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On second foreach loop you are printing same variable which you have used for column name, so its printing the column name also for second loop, edited code below please check, to print table data you need to print result of query

```
<?php

$dataconn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
$res = mysqli_query($dataconn, $sql);
$show = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$col = $show[0];
$columns = array();
echo "<pre>";
foreach ($col as $key => $value) {
    if (is_string($key)) {
        $columns[] = $key;
    }
}
echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr>";
foreach ($columns as $value) {
    echo "<td>$value</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";

foreach ($show as $tableData) {
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach ($tableData as $key => $val) {
        echo "<td>$val</td>";
    }
    echo   "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Can you write the full code for this table.

Comment: @DilipKumar this is full code just change table name on my query.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop does not iterate over the array with data. It is only displaying the same value N times.

Your approach to displaying HTML table with header is a little bit too complex. MySQLi has a special function called `fetch_fields()` that will give you metadata about the columns in the result. You can use that to display the header row.

```
echo '<table>';
    // Display table header
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach ($res->fetch_fields() as $column) {
        echo '<th>'.htmlspecialchars($column->name).'</th>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
```

If the result set also contains actual data then you can iterate the array with data and display it row by row.

```
    $show = mysqli_fetch_all($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    // If there is data then display each row
    if ($show) {
        foreach ($show as $row) {
            echo '<tr>';
            foreach ($row as $cell) {
                echo '<td>'.htmlspecialchars($cell).'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    }
echo '</table>';
```