# Create a generic function to generate html tables from mySQL database with Php

Tags: php, html, mysql

As you can read in the title, I'm trying to create a generic function in order to generate a table from a mySQL database.
I want to reuse it for every table I need to create in this project and for the next ones.

```
function table_generator($nameTable, $db) {

    $requete = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $nameTable);
    $requete->execute();
    $i = '0';

foreach($requete AS $data) {
        echo "<tr>";
        foreach($data as $vars){
            echo "<td>$vars</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Edit: the echo write every field twice.

Comment: Hint: You can `foreach` through `$data` as well

Comment: P.S. Unless you whitelist the table names this is going to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I did this, but it write every field twice...
Thank you for your advice about SQL injection, I'll take a look later on it.

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO here?

Comment: I'm using pdo, unfortunately I didn't find the issue. So I changed my script to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64293916/dynamic-table-in-html-using-mysql-and-php

Comment: Good idea...no point in re-inventing the wheel!