# PHP - displaying data in multiple html tables

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I've got a simple database table  with only 3 columns (team_id, question_id, answer).
I would like to display the data as following;

Team 1

1 (question_id) - blablabla (answer)

2 (question_id) - blablabla (answer)

""

Team 2

1 (question_id) - blablabla (answer)

2 (question_id) - blablabla (answer)

etc.

What is the best way to setup a nice foreach loop?

Comment: does it have to be _nice_? What have you tried, show us your best attempt (code). Please read [ask] and take the [tour]!

Comment: Doesn't have to be nice. I just have no clue how to set it up.

Comment: [show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-on-a-webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902483/show-values-from-a-mysql-database-table-inside-a-html-table-on-a-webpage)