# Display the sql query results in php

Tags: php

How can I display the following SQL query's results in PHP ?

```
SELECT CONCAT(
'SELECT `repagents`.full_name', GROUP_CONCAT('
, `t_', REPLACE(status, '`', '``'), '`.value
AS `', REPLACE(status, '`', '``'), '`'
SEPARATOR ''),
' FROM `repagents` ', GROUP_CONCAT('
LEFT JOIN `repagents` AS `t_', REPLACE(status, '`', '``'), '`
ON `repagents`.full_name = `t_', REPLACE(status, '`', '``'), '`.full_name
AND `t_', REPLACE(status, '`', '``'), '`.status = ', QUOTE(status)
SEPARATOR ''),
' GROUP BY `repagents`.full_name'
) INTO @qry FROM (SELECT DISTINCT status FROM `repagents`) t;
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Comment: This question is missing the following information: (1) the nature of the problem (2) what you have tried so far, (3) expected and (4) actual results.

Comment: I am a new user in php , I am getting the reults in mysql console but not able to form the table in php .

Comment: I want to display the results of the query in php

Comment: http://prntscr.com/6d3hzt

Please chk the screen shot I want to display it same in webpage using php.

Answer (score 0):

- Have a look at this [W3schools
  tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)
  explaining how to select data from MySQL in PHP.
- This [StackOverflow
  Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328349/displaying-query-result-in-a-html-table-in-php) adds how to build a simple HTML around a query.